# How to add/delete 2 or more fields in a form dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would want to have two or more fields in a form to be dynamically added and deleted as per requirement. Say for, a person can have more than 1 phone numbers and more than 1 email address. The idea is to let the user add more than one phone number and email address if they have

This down below is what I did (only a rough example)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10;
    var wrapper         = $(".container1"); 
    var add_button      = $(".add_form_field"); 

    var x = 0; 

    $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ 
            x++; 
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[' + x + ']"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
        else
        {
        alert('You Reached the limits')
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10;
    var wrapper         = $(".container2"); 
    var add_button      = $(".add_form_field_1"); 

    var x = 0; 

    $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ 
            x++; 
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="text[' + x + ']"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
        else
        {
        alert('You Reached the limits')
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
//I repeated the javascript for the first field which was this
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10;
    var wrapper         = $(".container1"); 
    var add_button      = $(".add_form_field"); 

    var x = 0; 

    $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ 
            x++; 
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[' + x + ']"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
        else
        {
        alert('You Reached the limits')
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
    <button class="add_form_field">Add New Field &nbsp; <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span></button>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="mytext[]">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container2">
    <button class="add_form_field_1">Add New Field &nbsp; <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span></button>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="text[]">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drgb4tw8/).

I am not a `javascript` coder hence do not know if this is how you do it or is there a better way.

P.S. I asked the same question an hour ago and had to rephrase it as it was causing confusion.

Comment: If the code is working in the way you want, this might be the wrong stackexchange for you. Check [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) for code improvements

Comment: @IanFako The code is only suitable for code review if it works, whereas the title is currently asking "how to do XY". It therefore needs at least a new title and a new description. See https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplyfy so much your code, check this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button.add_form_field").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $(this).closest(".container").find("input:first").attr("class")
        var numInputs = $(this).closest(".container").find("input").size()
        if (numInputs < 10) {
            numInputs++;
            if (name=="mytext"){
                $(this).closest(".container").append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[' + numInputs + ']"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>');
            }
            if (name=="text"){
                $(this).closest(".container").append('<div><input type="text" name="text[' + numInputs + ']"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>');
            }
        } else alert('You Reached the limits')
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <button class="add_form_field">Add New Field &nbsp; <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span></button>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="mytext[1]" class="mytext">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button class="add_form_field">Add New Field &nbsp; <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span></button>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="text[1]" class="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I checked, can you check the attribute name for both the fields ... the second field attribute name gets changed to mytext[] instead of text[].

Comment: You want add inputs with text[] name for the second container right?

Comment: I have two fields ... both should be dynamic ... 2 different fields with 2 different attribute name to it. So yeah.

Comment: SilverSurfer, the name attribute should have been name="mytext[0]" name="mytext[1]" name="mytext[2]" and so on for the first field .... for the second field it should be name="text[1]", name="text[2]", name="text[3]" ... but your code if click the first field twice and then the second field thrice the attribute name comes up not as inteneted.

Comment: do one thing ... add two mytext fields and then add 3 text fields ... check all their attribute names ... it will be mytext[0], mytext[1] for the first field and for the second field it will be text[], text [3], text[4] ...

Comment: Check it again.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a working example, Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you Mecom

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function removeUserDetail(index)
{
    var rows=jQuery("#user_info tr").length;
    jQuery("#user_info tr:nth-child("+(index+1)+")").remove();

    if(index==(rows-1))
    {
        jQuery("#user_info tr:nth-child("+(index)+")").children().eq(4).append('<a class="mc_plus_button" id="plus_1" href="javascript:void();" onclick="addUserDetail();" title="add"><strong>+</strong></a>');
    }
    jQuery("#user_info tr").each(function(i,e){
        if(i>1)
        {
            jQuery(this).children().eq(4).children().eq(0).attr("onclick","removeUserDetail("+i+");");
        }
        });
}
      function addUserDetail() {
        var row_count1 = jQuery("#user_info tr").length;
        var row_count = 0;
        jQuery(".tr_clone").each(function(index, value) {
          var rowid = jQuery(this).data('rowid');
          if (rowid > row_count) {
            row_count = rowid;
          }
        });
        row_count = row_count + 1;

        jQuery("#user_info tr").eq(row_count1 - 1).find(".mc_plus_button").remove();
        var html = '<tr class="tr_clone" data-rowid="' + row_count + '"><td>' + row_count + '</td>';
        html += '<td style="text-align: center"><input type="text" name="user_info[name][]" id="name_'+row_count+'" aria-invalid="false" /></td>';
        html += '<td style="text-align: center"><input type="text" name="user_info[email][]" id="email_'+row_count+'" aria-invalid="false" /></td>';

        html += '<td style="text-align: center"><input type="text" name="user_info[contact][]" id="contact_'+row_count+'" aria-invalid="false" /></td>';

        html += '<td><a class="mc_minus_button" id="minus_' + row_count + '" href="javascript:void();" onclick="removeUserDetail(' + row_count + ');" title="remove"><strong>&ndash;</strong></a><a class="mc_plus_button" href="javascript:void();" onclick="addUserDetail();" title="add"><strong>+</strong></a></td></tr>';

        jQuery("#user_info").append(html);

      }
</script>

<table id="user_info">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr_clone" data-rowid="1">
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td style="text-align: center">
      <input type="text" name="user_info[name][]" id="name_1" aria-invalid="false" />
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center">
      <input type="text" name="user_info[email][]" id="email_1" aria-invalid="false" />
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center">
      <input type="text" name="user_info[contact][]" id="contact_1" aria-invalid="false" />
    </td>
    <td><a class="mc_plus_button" href="javascript:void();" onclick="addUserDetail();" title="add"><strong>+</strong></a></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```